# Can JSR 305's "@WillClose" (et al) annotation, or one to the same effect, be implemented in/for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, eclipse-plugin

**tl;dr**: I want to tell Eclipse that my auxiliary method `closedown(AutoCloseable... aaa)` DOES in fact close all the AutoCloseable objects it's given.

On to the details:

I inherited a set of large Java applications with an ungodly amount of poorly written DAO classes. Far too many methods do a long sequence of SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries, reusing the PreparedStatement and ResultSet objects and whatnot, *sometimes* closing the resources before reusing them again; Eclipse produced hundreds of "Resource leak: 'rs' is not closed at this location" warnings.

As part of the code purification process, and to make cleansing easier, I wrote an auxiliary method `closedown(AutoCloseable... aaa)` that simply does an `if (a!=null) a.close();` for each given object; this one-liner can then be easily inserted before any `conn.prepareStatement()` call and whatnot...

... but now Eclipse produces almost as many "Potential resource leak: 'ps' may not be closed at this location" spurious info messages. I *am* placing the closedown() calls correctly (including in a finally block for each and every one of the try block in those classes), so the problem is simply that Eclipse that can not tell from its own source code analysis that things are fine.

These applications run on Java 7 (migrating to Java 8 is finally underway). This means I can use try-with-resources, BUT... the high amount of reuse of Statement, PreparedStatement and ResultSet objects make that tactic viable only for Connection objects. I don't want to use the @SuppressWarnings tag for the obvious reason. Instead, I would like to be able to tell Eclipse that the AutoCloseable objects sent to closedown() are indeed closed, so Eclipse will know to not produce those spurious messages.

Turns out that JSR 305 ended up dead, and yet, something like `@WillClose` would be a good fit for what I need (and `@WillNotClose` for handling certain Connection parameters!). So, how can this annotation be implemented on Eclipse?

————————————————————————————————————————————

EDIT: As requested by howlger, this is a minimal reproducible example. Consider this utility class:

```
package misc.util;

public class Closer {

    public static void closedown(final AutoCloseable... objects) {
        if (objects != null) {
            for (AutoCloseable o : objects) {
                try {
                    if (o != null) {
                        o.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Unexpected error when trying to close object: '" + o.toString() + "'.");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static java.sql.Connection getConnection() { return null; }
}
```

And this "main" class:

```
package misc.demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import static misc.util.Closer.closedown;
import static misc.util.Closer.getConnection;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet         rs = null;

        try (Connection conn = getConnection();) { // Eclipse doesn't notice a null object is coming (doesn't matter for our purposes now).

            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 'a' from dual");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 'b' from dual"); // Warning: "Resource leak: 'ps' is not closed at this location"
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            closedown(rs, ps);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 'c' from dual"); // Info: "Potential resource leak: 'ps' may not be closed at this location"
            rs = ps.executeQuery(); // ························ // Info: "Potential resource leak: 'rs' may not be closed at this location"

            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 'd' from dual"); // Eclipse knows everything is fine here (unlike above).
            rs = ps.executeQuery(); // ························ // Eclipse knows everything is fine here (unlike above).

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closedown(rs, ps);
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse identifies a *bona fide* resource leak in the "select 'b'" line (one that should not be suppressed!).

Eclipse also identifies two **potential** leaks in the "select 'c'" lines, which just add noise, as we know closedown() already deals with them. It's these last two "info" messages I want to get rid of; one way of doing it would be to tell that to Eclipse, by adding the @WillClose annotation (if it existed... but it doesn't).

Comment: There is no _but_, use try-with-resources statement instead of making your code harder to read by adding unnecessary stuff. `if (a!=null) a.close();` is not the same as try-with-resources. Think what happens when `close()` throws an exception. Better right-click your project, choose _Source > Clean Up..._ and use the _Java Features > Java 7: Use try-with-resource_ clean-up.

Comment: I am already doing that on the simpler methods that execute a single query on a fixed number of arguments; the same tactic becomes insufficient when dealing with complex methods that contain business logic, or execute the same query over every item in a list, or do one query with a variable number of arguments — at some point, some rs or ps objects will have to be reassigned, and try-with-resources doesn't cut it anymore (as it makes its variables final).

Also, remember that I *am* closing every AutoCloseable object in a finally block, so exceptions are well covered already.

Comment: Eclipse has built-in support for null annotations, but not for `@WillClose`, `@WillNotClose`, etc. If JSR 305 had not been rejected, it would probably be different now. Java 8 provides lambda expressions, which makes it easier to pass around functions that operate on resources rather than pass around the resources themselves. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I doubt `@WillClose` is the only and best solution for your real problem (see [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: JSR 305 wasn't rejected, it was abandoned.

Comment: Example added. This should help clear up what I want.

Comment: @mernst Yes, JSR 305 wasn't rejected, but is dormant: [_"The Executive Committee voted to list this JSR as dormant in May 2012"_](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305).

Comment: With the following utility method you would be able to get a `ResultSet` that can be used in a try-with-resources statement, so that all resources will be closed without calling `close()` explicitly: `private static ResultSet prepareStatementAndExecuteQuery(Connection connection, String sql) throws SQLException { if (connection == null) return null; try (PreparedStatement statement= connection.prepareStatement(sql)) { return statement.executeQuery(); } }`. _"Eclipse doesn't notice a null object is coming"_: `getConnection()` is not annotated as `Nullable` and can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Resource Leak Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#resource-leak-checker), which is distributed with the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).  The Resource Leak Checker guarantees, at compile time, that the program fulfills every object’s must-call obligations before the object is de-allocated.

This tool doesn't use JSR 305 annotations, but its own that are more general (they go beyond just closing resources).  For instance, for the `close()` method you would use
[`@MustCall("close")`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/mustcall/qual/MustCall.html) (though you don't need to, since the tool comes with JDK annotations), and you would use [`@EnsuresCalledMethods("close")`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/calledmethods/qual/EnsuresCalledMethods.html) rather than `@WillClose`, and [`@NotOwning`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/mustcall/qual/NotOwning.html) instead of `@WillNotClose`.

This is not built into Eclipse, but is a separate tool that can be [run from Eclipse](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#eclipse).

You should use Java’s try-with-resources statement when it is applicable, and the Resource Leak Checker will help you use it where appropriate.  However, try-with-resources can only close resource types that implement the `java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface, and it cannot handle common resource usage patterns that span multiple procedures.  The Resource Leak Checker is particularly useful in these situations.